# Getting JUnit Initialization error : org.objenesis.ObjenesisException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException in JDK17

Tags: java, maven, junit

I am using PowerMockito and Mockito for Junit(4) test class in JDK 17. But it is throwing some errors while doing "coverage as". We are using the following dependencies version:
powerMockito version - 1.7.4 , Mockito - 1.10.19.

While doing "coverage as" in my test case getting the below error:

Initialization error:

```
org.objenesis.ObjenesisException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryHelper.newConstructorForSerialization(SunReflectionFactoryHelper.java:54) at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:41) at org.objenesis.strategy.StdInstantiatorStrategy.newInstantiatorOf(StdInstantiatorStrategy.java:68) at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.getInstantiatorOf(ObjenesisBase.java:94) at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.newInstance(WhiteboxImpl.java:259) at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.newInstance(Whitebox.java:139) at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.getPowerMockTestListenersLoadedByASpecificClassLoader(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:95) at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:174) at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:48) at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:108) at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:71) at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:36) at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.(PowerMockRunner.java:34) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104) at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86) at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59) at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
```

Any help here can be appreciate.

Comment: First remove powerMockito (it's in itself a smell) and use a more recent version of Mockito...the ones you are using is very old...